# How to use different controller for my home page if the user is authenticated?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Based on the documentation and other blog posts it seems that from ASP.NET Core 3.0 you need to implement a `DynamicRouteValueTransformer` to dynamically change the route for a given path. For me it would mean that I need to create a `HomePageTransformer` like this:

```
    public class HomeRouteTransformer : DynamicRouteValueTransformer
    {
        public override async ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary> TransformAsync(
            HttpContext httpContext,
            RouteValueDictionary values)
        {
            if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // return RouteValueDictionary for authenticated users.
            }
            else
            {
                // return RouteValueDictionary for anonymous users.
            }
        }
    }
```

and then register this in the Startup configuration:

```
endpoint.MapDynamicControllerRoute<HomeRouteTransformer>("/");
```

The problem is that at this point the User is empty (i.e. doesn't have any claims and is not authenticated), even if it should be filled with data because the user should be authenticated in the request. It seems that implementing an `DynamicRouteValueTransformer` is not the right approach here. Any suggestions?

Comment: As an alternative approach, you could also check whether the user is authenticated in the home page action and redirect to the other controller/action in this case. This would be much easier if it is just about showing a different view if the user is authenticated.

Comment: Sounds good and something similar would be an alternative approach but using an ActionFilter instead of redirecting from an actual action.

Comment: Rrdirecting is the easiest way if you only need it at one spot. If you can integrate it into an existing Action Filter, e.g. for authentication, this is also a good way.

Comment: I'd add that my ultimate goal is to keep the user on the home page with a different content (so keep the path as "/") so while redirect works for me as a workaround my goal is not redirecting the user to a different URL.

Comment: Then you can also return a different view from your Action method depending on whether the user is authenticated or not.